# Creating a clock program

Tags: c, clock

Write  a clock program to achieve the following function:
a) Press any key to start the timer;
b) Press the 'S' key to start the timer, press the 'E' key to stop the timer or when the time is 00:00:00 o'clock.

Here is what I have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
main()
{
 long int t;
 int flag =0;
 t = 86400;
 printf("press S start, press E stop\n");
 while(1)
 {
  if (kbhit()== 'S' || kbhit() == 's')
   flag =1;
  if (getch() == 'E' || getch() == 'e')
  { flag =0;
   continue;
  }
  if(t <= 0)
   break;
  if(flag == 1)
  {
  t=t-1;
  Sleep(1000);
  printf("%d ",t);
  }
 }
}
```

Well, I don't really know how to achieve the control function.How can I press 'E' to give the timer stop, and press 'S' give the timer run again.

I am a beginner and cannot get the right program over and over again.  I hope you can help me.  Thanks!

Comment: Show us your code so we can show you what's wrong with it. We will not do your homework for you.

Comment: Showing your code somebody could help

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
main()
{
 long int t;
 int flag =0;
 t = 86400;
 printf("press S start, press E stop\n");
 while(1)
 {
  if (kbhit()== 'S' || kbhit() == 's')
   flag =1;
  if (getch() == 'E' || getch() == 'e')
  { flag =0;
   continue;
  }
  if(t <= 0)
   break;
  if(flag == 1)
  {
  t=t-1;
  Sleep(1000);
  printf("%d ",t);
  }
 }
}

Comment: For starters, why are you comparing `kbhit()` with 'S'? `kbhit()` returns `bool`.

Comment: You want to do something closer to `int ch = getch(); if (ch == 'E' || ch == 'e') flag =0;`.  Presently you are typically trying to get a char twice per your `while()` loop.  `kbhit()` return 0 or non-0 to indicate a key is available,  It does not return the char.  There are other issues too.  Carefully re-code. Ask again if needed with a well presented question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `kbhit()` twice, only once is needed per loop.  It does not return a `char`.
You are calling `getch()` twice, you only need to once per loop.
You should improve what `flag` means.  Maybe change to `StoppedFlag`.

```
 while (1) {
  if (kbhit()) {
    char ch = getch();
    if ((ch == 'S') || (ch == 's')) {
      flag = 0;
    }
    else if ((ch == 'E') || (ch == 'e')) {
      flag = 1;
    }
  }
  else {
    if(t <= 0) {
      break;
    }
    if (flag == 0) {
      t=t-1;
      Sleep(1000);
      printf("%ld ", t);
    }
  }
}
```